# Not able to find classids and interfaces ids in registry

Tags: com, windbg

I am trying to debug some exe in windbg. Now its calling some thirdparty com dll which is exposing DLLGetClassObject function.

DLLGetClassObject signature is

```
HRESULT __stdcall DllGetClassObject(
  __in   REFCLSID rclsid,
  __in   REFIID riid,
  __out  LPVOID *ppv
);
```

Looking at stack trace and arguments I can find out the class id and interface id using commands

> dt GUID [address]

When I try to search these guids in  registry , I am not able to find anything.

Is there something wrong? I should be able to see the com classes and interfaces id in regsitry.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably... If you follow the callstack, is `DllGetClassObject` invoked by any COM runtime function (`CoCreateInstance`, `CoGetClassObject`)?

If so, your CLSID should be found under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID. The interfaces aren't necessarily registered.

Note that there's nothing to prevent an app from loading a DLL and calling DllGetClassObject manually, as long as it knows the threading model requirements of the object to be created.

Comment: so it means that if DllGetClassObject is not called by COM functions then it is not a COM object?
and the input parameters can be anything other than clsid or interface ids.

Comment: Sort of. It is still a COM object, it's just that it doesn't allow the client to use standard COM activation to instantiate it.

Comment: It's also possible that COM APIs did invoke DllGetClassObject, but the DLL implementing the COM objects is using registration-free COM.  In this case, you won't necessarily find any registrations in the registry either...

Comment: Good point, Reuben. In that case you should be able to find a manifest next to the application's .exe, describing where the server is and what its threading model requirements are, right?

Answer (score 1):

I have another, unrelated, theory -- do you have symbols for the third-party DLL?

If not, the entry in the callstack for a call into said module is usually shown as the offset of the first export in the module + some large offset.

If DllGetClassObject is elected as the "base export" for the module, and the .exe calls a COM method hosted in the module, the callstack will show something like:

```
  DllGetClassObject + 0x112313
  UseThirdPartyCOMThing + 0x20
```

where 0x112313 is larger than what you'd expect the code size of DllGetClassObject to be.

So, it could be a red herring -- you might just be seeing a call into the DLL at some offset that isn't matched in your available symbols, and the debugger shows it using whatever information it has available.

Comment: +1 for asking to check for large offset: In a DLL exposing COM objects, traces with any of the "trivially" exported functions is usually a red-herrying: `DllCanUnloadNow`, `DllGetClassObject`, `DllInstall`, `DllRegisterServer`, and `DllUnregisterServer`.